# How to show the average value in Radar Chart with Vega

Tags: charts, kibana, vega-lite, vega, radar-chart

I am trying to build a radar chart using Vega.

My example data is like below:

```
"data": [
{
  "name": "table",
  "values": [
    {
      "country": "Egypt",
      "Rating": 9,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "General Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "Coffee"
    },
    {
      "country": "Japan",
      "Rating": 8,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "General Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "Digital"
    },
    {
      "country": "Greece",
      "Rating": 4,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "Medicine"
    },
    {
      "country": "France",
      "Rating": 8,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "HR"
    },
    {
      "country": "Japan",
      "Rating": 7,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "Digital"
    },
    {
      "country": "Japan",
      "Rating": 10,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "Pc"
    },
    {
      "country": "Japan",
      "Rating": 8,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "Pc"
    },
    {
      "country": "Japan",
      "Rating": 8,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "Medicine"
    },
    {
      "country": "Denmark",
      "Rating": 3,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "Pc"
    },
    {
      "country": "Netherlands",
      "Rating": 6,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "General Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "HR"
    },
    {
      "country": "Turkiye",
      "Rating": 5,
      "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
      "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
      "department_displayvalue": "Coffee"
    }
  ]
```

I was able to create a radar chart using online examples(below link). But I want to show the average value instead of every value per department. Coloring by survey is not important at the moment. How can I change this code to use average rating?

Any help is appreciated!

[My code in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aACwAGNTPg0yWVRpk4kChTXFl9MpA0xsINAF5w0oTAE8cz9OInOZUCUwkMwg0ECMTMwsAXxl7MnEkABtQ1ABtUESELxAAJ2MaBlCZBhwFJEwc+SUYAAICWoAmEGiAXRlyoLQMkCycoKYkvxBiZIY4VJ6AhnFMXLcwgFEyD0xpEAAlCqi0AE4ZIIBrOHEAfQkwxrVGgEYAWjUANgfd2pu1VA1UAQB2dYViKcIAxcqQFugAOInOD5JK1ACCOBwSRoUG2ElqAA1PLkaCcoHBagBlEFg-5wIy5TDZWanUwQZFINyjJLjMIAYTYADMuXBnLFQNNZvMwgApJBGSQyLaYHaoAAcByQxzOF3QV1uD2eale70+H1+-0BwNBcHBICh4hhyQRSJRaNlGOxMLx4gJxNJZvJlOpJ0wdJoDKSTJZbPQABEdHRki0pIK2DM5uaIbk+QT1jK5SolSrzpJ1dd7k8Xm8Pl9DR1jZ7zQAhIpmCYQW3I1Ho8RYnGu90k00LDoUpBUmn++mM5ljHIAWTgpigDdj8cTIvQADF8m7hpnzGhFSAjic85dC1qS3ry39K0Dq2E6-YrRAm4iWw72O3nbj8YSe2T+z7hwGgxDCcwgACQ2BcQCFJMxQlJApU2bZt1QH4cwPNUQA1IttV1MsDQvEAASvXsb3re9HztVtHTfTtPw9Yjf0HX1aVHYNx1ZHJI1oIIkggqDlxAcVJQzRCLFQd5UNVfMMOPYsdVLfVvnwwiTTJdBbwbB9m3tNsOxdWjvy9Bihz9ACx1DHIAAUoF4hNhXNQS4OE2UkN3fdJKPTVZJwhSKwIqtiLU0jGy0yjX10j8Nzon8CIHYzmMDMzgPQKybKXezYPgrdRNc5U0KkzCTzks88KNIjVJAdSyJCl8nRoyKDL7GK-xMligPYsJp1necBUg2zoIjE5kFyQ4nLlABmCTDwLTzsPk89SpUr1ArvYKn20qjwq7L9ryMpiRwS1jzLCFKer480ADk4HoGFg3EBRigQ5zRMeSb0IKry5pKy9FuTaFYWqnT3y2qLDKaxj-1atiwxAMDUrssIABUQUOGg3E3ES0AEV78pk2bisUhbr2WjTyOfQG6u7Hawbi-bAKhnJOR5PkWlaHq+jCY43AesQQXTdABiGdY5jgiAuTYXIEG6VwPByJAyDIVMKEqdYFYTHAmHBNJqb20zDuA1mDbiNEhkmTIkGyMI4LIBhg1yIWZbCHA2DMNYZHXMgvFAeJEh49A0juCyAEkpFqIPWljcJjFMJC1EoLGCLYZAzBcAiKhQfmkEGYYuTxJIFDCBRYp1yGjuiNnzZyfJTBjA4HfQFErUHdZ3c9kBvZjP3NFqKvCggcPYhAJxcjYNA5nGGRxFRLwuWSCA4A6RPgnzUBOnTvdM8FmQc7gPOwiyiOFEXsxJ2Tz5y4t9AAiScX7c8MJxejmuE6T5fU66DOs-Wbfd-QZTrwHluKcuCIFllAAkswWhtBkPiNghcU5+hhCnAAHkAnQPswg9yKBHcEXs0EdzyAULBZcB5DUOKbPcdcQCq1KOsdml8KjkHFniB6DgzCFxQWJLew9JaoFADPAkaxeFvzXgLYYdCQD8KuirYepQNbdD8mVL0rMSGDjIVLChd967zgnhXMIDpGHzDuA3bO3CU6rzCJItYA8YFwKEQgu2QiXYwidsGZWQijpaMbrkO4UBr5z3zgPDhuCEj4OgMkOAAAKAA5D3ZIUSQ6dAYAgSgWUACUtQABUtQAgQAiWEoY0SrY20HPE2oiTkmF2avFOm5lUmpOwagkJvs27G0iTEgocSEkVCSSkkS6Ssl3jya0wp5him5FKeUyglTwYtQOm1cYdSI4QDmGwY4QDWl6LYNfO2W9c751-v5MkA9lnD2OAAdUUModxSUbgDxzkkX2XsNmXy2TfXZO99kKJ+hHe5SQADyRg5zuBTh42OtziFxg0f0OASDXa9F0egcydxKiwq-qYoR5j6GVDIOLNwRjurQLdLA1u9jkGNPQb-bpySUEDxwW3PBzTJkLAHiiwRwSKVvx6ZM-eA9khoJBUlSCpKB5MCQHPYxAr2roAQIoBQgs7k0AeZK6GgwkBQBGsQtoPV3CaLyDbMRCKCHVySHcBWig0WJzMWnDmZpQgD1YXdGFaBNAgBsSS2YiChFBJGElNQtLlVeD9TIJBzQhHt2aZgpsWSclDPCSM62tsJlUqmUXCGcz6aLNpaG9l+DI2ZNqIM-JbSimJq6ZgLlqbZk1InJmuIKy1nXKlSAFEuhMAKyZEs+tcALk1ADWgRomrIU6uhainRF8QCcyMZnHeFqeEr2tegTmdqZAOvYWgG4hKAi2NAKSr15L8ERLzQAalqAIfp2S7CxoKVEktJSy0VqqbTRK7Fa0gDpeGsIh7CFNhPWe-Nhbhk3tGaWspybpk011vMuAr7WUp2-p88Dxd02lysC2-MPRKjLMtkwXJRb41jKTeWiplbqnPoWekgAfKHQO9QmjrA8XkHQegeoMaGFyKx7QQCivFfOdIrgJiCJaXGoDCa72gaIymx9kGM21Co2oejgrbA4AgphwTeGRMEfvcRqTJca21AALz6dqPJmQDGZUmHlZChjTA2DYEtVAiRirHk+qbaq9VPzAhnLgExtlLmVVbICRC6WuqJVjpyAmSo3jQsSPRfO9+RqaDJFNbiAJm7iXwI9Q40ATjcguIYX2zxcBBw+L8TOCO3r4NhBDQ0oRlX0BuGaMcrtBXm0+fbcyutpzu2XJgAV8FZdWZAA)

Answer (score 1):

It appears what you are looking for is a transformation. In particular the [aggregate transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/aggregate/), here is the working example you'll need to implement.

```
  "transform": [
    {
      "type": "aggregate",
      "groupby": [
        "department_displayvalue"
      ],
      "fields": [
        "Rating"
      ],
      "ops": [
        "average"
      ],
      "as": [
        "Rating"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I ended up with this... [this is the source code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aACwAGNTPg0yWVRpk4kChTXFl9MpA0xsINAF5w0oTAE8cz9OInOZUCUwkMwg0ECMTMwsAXxl7MnEkABtQ1ABtUESELxAAJ2MaBlCZBhwFJEwc+SUYAAICWoAmEGiAXRlyoLQMkCycoKYkvxBiZIY4VJ6AhnFMXLcwgFEyD0xpEAAlCqi0AE4ZIIBrOHEAfQkwxrVGgEYAWjUANgfd2pu1VA1UAQB2dYViKcIAxcqQFugAOInOD5JK1ACCOBwSRoUG2ElqAA1PLkaCcoHBagBlEFg-5wIy5TDZWanUwQZFINyjJLjMIAYTYADMuXBnLFQNNZvMwgApJBGSQyLaYHaoAAcByQxzOF3QV1uD2eale70+H1+-0BwNBcHBICh4hhyQRSJRaNlGOxMLx4gJxNJZvJlOpJ0wdJoDKSTJZbPQABEdHRki0pIK2DM5uaIbk+QT1jK5SolSrzpJ1dd7k8Xm8Pl9DR1jZ7zQAhIpmCYQW3I1Ho8RYnGu90k00LDoUpBUmn++mM5ljHIAWTgpigDdj8cTIvQADF8m7hpnzGhFSAjic85dC1qS3ry39K0Dq2E6-YrRAm4iWw72O3nbj8YSe2T+z7hwGgxDCcwgACQ2BcQCFJMxQlJApU2bZt1QH4cwPNUQA1IttV1MsDQvEAASvXsb3re9HztVtHTfTtPw9Yjf0HX1aVHYNx1ZHJI1oIIkggqDlxAcVJQzRCLFQd5UNVfMMOPYsdVLfVvnwwiTTJdBbwbB9m3tNsOxdWjvy9Bihz9ACx1DHIAAUoF4hNhXNQS4OE2UkN3fdJKPTVZJwhSKwIqtiLU0jGy0yjX10j8Nzon8CIHYzmMDMzgPQKybKXezYPgrdRNc5U0KkzCTzks88KNIjVJAdSyJCl8nRoyKDL7GK-xMligPYsJp1necBUg2zoIjE5kFyQ4nLlABmCTDwLTzsPk89SpUr1ArvYKn20qjwq7L9ryMpiRwS1jzLCFKer480ADk4HoGFg3EBRigQ5zRMeSb0IKry5pKy9FuTaFYWqnT3y2qLDKaxj-1atiwxAMDUrssIABUQUOGg3E3ES0AEV78pk2bisUhbr2WjTyOfQG6u7Hawbi-bAKhnJOR5PkWnaPd1wgLk2FyBBulcDwciQMgyFTChKnWYWExwJhwTSam9tMw7gNZrk8SSe7ukenZWbYPANaQUh8jIZxWaQSZNe3Vo2h6vowmONwHrEEF03QAYhnWOY4I5rmefSPnPDCQXhb4MWZAl0ppY1hRYvlyGjst+O4jRIZJkyJBsgD8wGGDXJ3f5sIcDYMw1hkdcjZcEB4kSHj0DSO4LIASSkWoG9aWNwmMUwkLUSgsYIthkDMcvOhQF2kEGYYVbgNWwij5r4rpo7omttOcnyUwYwOPP0BRK1B3WUuvFASuYxrzRajXwoIFb2IQCcXI2DQOZxhkcRUS8LlkggOAOn74J81AYeYRXYT1VgoMIWU24KF-mYScg9PjL3TugAISQua539ugLmncN59wHv-AiFQR57jHm7GQk9p7oGUteG+B9y5cEQALKABJZgtDaDIfEbAo7lz9DCcuAAPWhOgq5hAvkUNu4Ij6CJPnkAooil43yGocFOe4t4gDDjgdYNskEVHIFzPED0HBmCjvwsSpD74+1AB-AkaxUAAIIUA4hwxNEgEsVdcW99w4yz8mVL0lt5GDkUbzZR6CQA70cSvMIDodHzDuKE9YXIzFDzsegFxawb7sM4TYkA3Cc6ZKLjCAuwYxaZKOtvBsg47hQBQV-MBN9jESISFI6AyQ4AAAoADkF9khtKbp0BgCBKBZQAJS1AAFS1ACBAFpTShjtLgmQLOg5um1F6f02e4MWoHTauMQZgyxECIadXCuSdWkdIKF0npFQ+kDJEsMsZd4pnHNmZnbOSyVmUDWTTBWWy4A7LbhAOYbBji0OOREtgKCc6kNATPfyZIb7-PvscAA6ooZQxSko3BvirJI1cj4gqQWC1BkKp5gIoTCr0mKaDYoAPJGDnO4cuJTu4YrkXGIJ-Q4C8OLr0cJ6BzJ3EqJyuJCTMmAK0ZUMgXM3AxO6mwt0HDD5ZNmDwzJdSK6SMOW8-hN9xFqoOTPS5-SFg3wFdY+pQiKEGveZaiBN9kiCIZUlSC2S25MFNlPecaL2roAQIoBQbsKXYodV6kAgwkBQBGnIq2rL3DBNyFnMJiDpHrySHcYWighX90SV0dAdtQg3wMXdDlaBNCKoCBk0AzqVVBrDGobV1avC1pkLw5omTj6HJEU2MZEyHnNKefMl5FzMBXI+THTZ9NfnapbWaqRHbRm1HudMk5cyFm5FeZakdEMx3mQnXEAFQLPXQxRLoTAwsmR-L3XAZFNR61oEaJG6NKiTUaJ5SAO2MSx5TwzeY-B2bX1mjzTIAtRi0A3FlWWhVlbQCqrbWEFps6ADUtQBC3PGXYHtMy2nLoHcs9d0dN0LwnDukAOqYPoDgzIpsiHkNzoXY8zDzzFmDuHXhjZBH2JEafZkshJK5b4cSu1W1R78w9EqP8gOTBJmLr7SutdQ7Vksfnvx7ZwyAB8zd671CaOsEpeQdB6B6jpoYXJUms1dV-WJvs9wTGsUc3t9H+2MZw3J95CnaZKZ+bUNTahtOOtsOonqombNSfszJpj8m55ucVux2oABeGLtRvMyB0z6kw-rWU6aYGwbAmbWHOMpTikYjrQ3hrbpzWYiK4B6dNYV4NmXp73r9jkWJL8X0JkqLkaVVov1ZsIZ0lNaaalgflVwpVOTQB5NyAU7RN7Sm7w65UuwM426qu42EZteyuNQvQG4ZocKL0zZCVV09Rrd0IsvSimAM3mVL0tkAA).
[image]

Comment: Oh! I always added average aggregation transform outside of the data, that might be the reason it didn't work for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes I think so, and no worries.